# What is the spacing for trek 1.1?

Tags: road-bike, hub, trek

I'm trying to find new wheels for my trek 1.1, and I can't find the spacing for the hubs. The wheels I'm looking at have a front spacing of 100mm, and a back spacing of 130mm. Will these fit on my bike?

Answer (score 2):

Road front hubs are 100 mm and 8-10 speed rear hubs are 130 mm.

In the case of the Trek 1.1, it's always been spec'd with a 8 speed rear hub, so those wheels should fit on the bike.

Comment: In any case, it's probably a good idea to just measure. The valid options are in 5 mm increments, so even a basic measuring tape or ruler will suffice. It's not like it's a seatpost where you need a micrometer to figure out what width they ended up using.

Comment: Actually, 6 and 7 speed road hubs are 126 mm in the rear :)

Comment: You're right, I should have typed 4mm rather than 5mm. Looking at the [standard spacings](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#standard) it seems that all the spacings used are 4 or 5 mm apart at minimum.  Still, a ruler should suffice for any measurements of the hub.